# What is the best practice to create MSI with some other child MSI as prerequisite?

Tags: wix, inno-setup, bootstrapper, prerequisites, burn

Currently we are using [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) as a bootstrapper to install the MSI prerequisites. It makes bit complex to maintain the setup. I found the [Burn tool](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) which may help us to resolve this issue by having a single setup to install whatever we need. I could not find either documentation or sample for this tool. Is anyone have idea about this? Or is there an alternative solutio?

I am looking for the alternative solution for the actions that we do with the ISS bootstrapper now:

1. Extract the files (Main setup, Prerequisite setup)
2. Need to ensure prerequisites status and install on demand.
3. Start main install.

Comment: Keep a close eye on Rob's blog, because in this newer post he promises to give more information soon: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/1/15/Burn-moves-to-a-new-foundation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Burn tool is still a bit raw to be used in production. Many people in the [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) community recommend [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/).

Comment: Great. Thanks Yan for pointing out this. Will make of use it.

Comment: Well, if you build a Managed Bootstrapper, while taking advantage of Net Framework 4 + WPF, it can become really awesome..