# Run second installer after completion of first

Tags: windows-installer

I have created two windows-installer A.msi and B.msi.
I want B.msi should start after completion of A.msi.
How can I add some functionality in A.msi which start another installer.
I am using Wix.

I add CustomAction in .wxs file

```
<CustomAction ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"" Return="asyncNoWait" Execute="immediate" Id="RunSecondMSI"  />
```

AND in InstallExecuteSequence  table

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="RunSecondMSI" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launching the second MSI through a custom action scheduled after InstallFinalize (in InstallExecuteSequence table). This custom action should use the **msidbCustomActionTypeAsync** and **msidbCustomActionTypeContinue** flags (asynchronous execution, do not wait for return).

You cannot launch another MSI directly, but you can try using "cmd.exe /k". For example:

```
cmd.exe /k msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"
```

SourceDir property is automatically set to the package folder path (I assumed the MSI files are in the same folder).

Comment: Hi,Can u see image i have added in which i add custom action called RunSecondMSI and set its property.Now how can i set msidbCustomActionTypeAsync and msidbCustomActionTypeContinue flags?? and where i have to write command "cmd.exe /k msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi""

Comment: I have done some modification in Question.Would that changes work??

Comment: Did you see modification in Question.

Comment: The changes seem to be correct. Please escape the quotes in ExeCommand by using &quot;. Also, in InstallExecuteSequence the custom action should run "After" InstallFinalize.

Comment: Hi Cosmin,this solution really worked for me.But after completion of A.msi a command line prompt window appears on screen and remain until B.msi complete its installation process.Can we write any syntax in ExeCommand property so that when this hit B.msi command line prompt window should automatically close.

Comment: Try removing the cmd.exe part: msiexec.exe /i &quot;[SourceDir]B.msi&quot;

Comment: I tried ExeCommand="msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"" And also ExeCommand="/k msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"" but its not working.

Comment: how do i get complete folder path where i put A.msi & B.msi files.Currently i am using ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k msiexec.exe /i [WindowsFolder]\B.msi" that's why i have to put both A.msi and B.msi file in WINDOWS folder.but end user can put it in C:\,D:\ etc. drive.

Comment: I tried $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\B.msi , $(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)\B.msi but not working.

Comment: SourceDir property should be automatically resolved to the folder from which the MSI is launched. Did you escape the quotes by using &quot;?

Comment: I am trying for this one.My question is regarding "Try removing the cmd.exe part:" that posted earlier I tried ExeCommand="msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"" And also ExeCommand="/k msiexec.exe /i "[SourceDir]B.msi"" but its not working.

Comment: I should be ExeCommand="msiexec.exe /i &quot;[SourceDir]B.msi&quot;". If it doesn't work you can try creating a log of the main install to see what command line is used for the custom action.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin! I'll try for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [bootstrapper](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/Bootstrapper) for this kind of scenarios. Your question seems to duplicate [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335287/what-is-the-best-practise-to-create-msi-with-some-other-child-msi-as-prerequisite)