# Including wic_x86_enu.msi and vcredist_x86.msi in Setup Bootstrapper of a Visual Studio 2010 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installation, setup-project

I want to distribute my project which is written in VS2010 and C#. The project depends on DLL files that they need vcredist version 2008. How can I include that file in my setup file?

I also need to setup wic_x86_enu in destination system when it has XP SP2. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might find this one related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335287/what-is-the-best-practise-to-create-msi-with-some-other-child-msi-as-prerequisite

Comment: How are you creating your setup program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Setup project, select Project + Add, Merge Module.  Navigate to c:\program files\common files\merge modules and select "Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm" to get the C/C++ runtime DLLs deployed to the target machine.  There might be additional ones you need, like ATL, MFC, OpenMP, you didn't specify the exact dependencies in your question.

Beware that you'll have these merge modules available only if you have VS2008 installed on your machine.  If you don't then it is strongly recommended that you rebuild the DLLs or libraries you use on VS2010, you cannot effectively support your product otherwise.  If necessary, deploy the installer provided by a 3rd party if that's the way you ended up with a dependency on these DLLs.

Comment: You might be able to select the .msi instead of the merge module.  I don't see it complain but I never tried this.

Comment: .net framework 4.0 can not be installed on machines with winXP SP2 when wic is not installed yet.

Comment: You cannot deploy .NET 4.0 on XP SP2.  The machine *must* be updated to SP3.  Leave this up to the machine owner.  Even if you found a hack around this by installing WIC (rather an unlikely one btw), you should still not use this hack.  There is no telling what framework code is going to fail to work properly.  This is unsupportable.