# WIX Install ASP.NET MVC 1.0 MSI if Not Already Installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wix

I'm using WIX to Install an ASP.NET MVC 1.0.  It creates an Application Pool and a WebSite in IIS.

However the website maybe installed on servers that do not currently have ASP.NET MVC 1.0 installed.  Currently I have a WIX Condition setup to check for the existence of MVC 1.0.

```
<Condition Message="ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is required to proceed with the installation.">
     Installed OR ASP_NET_MVC_1_0_DLL
</Condition>

<Property Id="ASP_NET_MVC_1_0_DLL">
<DirectorySearch Id="MVC_DLL_DIR" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]\Microsoft  ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies">
         <FileSearch Id="MVC_DLL_FILE" Name="System.Web.Mvc.dll" MinVersion="1.0.40309"/>
</DirectorySearch>
```

I have an the ASP.NET MVC 1.0 MSI file that I have to manually install on the server before running the  I would like to "bundle" with the installer.  If MVC is not installed, the installer will run the MSI and install MVC automatically.

What is the simplest way to pull this off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best practise to create MSI with some other child MSI as prerequisite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335287/what-is-the-best-practise-to-create-msi-with-some-other-child-msi-as-prerequisite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done through prerequisites. MSI packages do not support them, so you need an [EXE bootstrapper](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/Bootstrapper).

You can also try [Burn in WiX 3.6](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) (it's currently in beta).

Comment: OK thanks... I guess I'm still trying to figure out exactly how this integrates with my current WIX MSI installer though.. any good information on that?

Comment: There is a reason why this is done through prerequisites. Windows Installer doesn't support two MSI packages running at the same time. So you cannot use a MSI to install another MSI. You need a bootstrapper which first installs the first MSI and only when it's finished launches the main installer.